# expanding TreeNode to show table c#

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I have a couple of Tables right now in which it is possible to fill out some information and submit something.

But instead of just having each table visible all the time, I'm trying to create sort of a menu that when you click a menu item, for instance create case the table for creating a case is opened between menu point "create case" and the one below (if there is one).

I'm trying with a Treeview at the moment but I can't really figure out how to "add" a table to a treenode if this is even possible?

Am I going at this the wrong way or is there some way of adding controls to TreeNodes ?

Comment: What technology are you using? Winforms, WPF...?

Comment: Making a sharepoint page by inheriting  System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebPart with .cs class. I realize there are sharepoint webparts but I don't have access to these.
In this .cs class I create controls and make them webbrowseable and that's basically it